# CakePHP - zero-to-many relationship

Tags: cakephp

In CakePHP, how do you setup a zero-to-many relationship?

For example, I have three models: Player, PitcherStats, and FielderStats.  A Player is either a Pitcher or a Fielder.  Accordingly, the Player will have (zero or many) Pitcher stats or (zero or many) Fielder stats.  The PitcherStats will have a belongsTo relationship to Player.  And so will the FielderStats.  How does the Player model relate to the other two?

Comment: In your code, model each like a 1-to-N relationship. It doesn't matter that no rows will exist in one of the two tables; no rows could always exist in a 1-to-N relationship if there's no related data yet.

Comment: The conflict is when I display a Players table, CakePHP looks for PitcherStats and FielderStats for every Player, but fails to find PitcherStats for fielders and FielderStats for pitchers.  And this results in an error.  The solution I've thought of so far is to leave out the Player hasMany

Comment: Ignore that unfinished comment above..  Player hasMany PitcherStat, FielderStat works.  Thanks! Is it better to have this relationship in the Model or bind it when necessary?  The problem is that there is a lot of data in the Stat tables, so viewing page that lists all the Players (and having this defined relationship) will take a long time to load.  An alternative would be to unbind the relationship in cases where many players are listed in a table.

Answer (score 0):

you should have one table for stats with foreign keys to the concrete stats. so you should build 3 tables for stats, one which will hold all stats (foreign key and type) and two will hold the concrete values.

Comment: My thinking might be a little off, but if I were to create models in this situation, I'd be in the same position.  Player hasMany (NewTable).  (NewTable) belongsTo Player.  But what about how NewTable relates to PitcherStat and FielderStat?  Would it still have zero-to-many relationships?  Is building that NewTable good practice?

Answer (score 0):

zero to x relation ship is a subgroup of 1/n to x relationships

there are in fact only 2:

- 1:n
- n:m

in different combinations and with different choices of foreign keys

e.g. 1:1 is nothing but 1:n where you can decide where to put the key (left or right table).

0:x is a simple case of 1:n or n:m where there is no record yet.